# Express — prevent form changing on client side

Tags: node.js, security, express, xss, client-side-validation

Let's say I have a such form:

```
// JADE
form(action="", method="POST")
    select(name="currency")
        option(value="EURUSD") EURUSD
        option(value="GBPUSD") GBPUSD
        option(value="USDCHF") USDCHF
    input(type="submit")

# CoffeeScript
sanitizer = require "any sanitizer" # to replace <,>,',", etc.
app.post "/add_currency", (req,res)->
    # I use Sequelize for storing data in MySQL
    Currency.create(
        name: santizer ( req.body.currency )
    ).success( (created_currency)->

    )
```

OK, we'll get an object:

```
{
    name: "EURUSD"
    id:   1
    ...
}
```

But, if we load form in browser, inspect `select(name="currency")`'s `option`s in Web Inspector (Chrome: Developer Tools), and change first option's value from "EURUSD" to "SOMETHING WIRED", the form will pass, and we'll have the object:

```
{
    name: "SOMETHING WIRED"
    id:   1
    ...
}
```

...assuming the fact, we have technically filtered our input with sanitizer! So, the question is:

**1. How to prevent changing input's predifined values?**

**2. How to prevent changing input's names?**

I've wrote a simple library to check if select's value from response is *in* values array sent to client, but it's very hard to manange. To prevent form names changing I check if array of sent input names is **exactly** the same as got from client.

P.S. Another solution may be using predefined database fields, accepting only several values. However, it's not a Grail 'cause options list may be dynamic-generated from actual database objects.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you receive from the client can be faked, so you therefore cannot prevent the client from changing the input's name and predefined values. To be sure you *must* do validation server-side, although you can use client-side JavaScript to make the process of altering form data more difficult for the client.

```
app.post('/add_currency', function(req, res) {
  var curr = req.body.currency;
  if (curr !== 'EURUSD' || curr !== 'GBPUSD' || curr !== 'USDCHF') {
    res.send(400);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already done this check, however my option list may be generated dynamicly, so every time I get data from client, I need to go to DB, get actual values list, compile an array with allowed values and check. I worry about performance. I mean, if there any module that can construct forms for me, store all values' list and after getting response, automatically check if it's not poisoned?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to adjust your thinking here if you are talking about security. The client at the other end of your TCP connection is untrusted. It might not be an actual web browser. It might be a program sending carefully-crafted malicious attacks. Don't think in terms of UI restrictions, asking the browser to enforce things for you, javascript regexes in the browser ensuring safe input. That's all missing the point. Just establish what does and does not constitute a valid/secure request in your server side code and enforce that with code in the server, sending the appropriate 4XX response when the request is not valid.

Another way to think of it, is trying to use HTML/JavaScript to "prevent changing" values in a web form is like putting a sign up on your house saying "Burglars, please knock on front door to request entry". Does you no good against non-malicious visitors and is utterly ignored by actual attackers.

Comment: Well, you're obviously right. However, as I mentioned above, I'm looking for any module that can construct forms for me, store all values and after getting response, automatically check if it's not poisoned. Have you met such ones?

Comment: Not to those exact specs, but http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-csrf.html provides nice cross-site request forgery protection.